# Find Grep Sed- any damage to UTMP WTMP and BTMP?

Tags: linux

Running a string search/replace search and concered that some strings may be contained in those files, does sed ignore them because of the binary type structure, or could they destroy the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a "try it and see what happens" sort of question, so...

- Start with a copy of the `wtmp` file.

  ```
  $ cp /var/log/wtmp wtmp.work
  ```
- Look at it using `who`:

  ```
  $ who wtmp.work
  lars     pts/2        2012-10-23 10:58 (:0)
  lars     pts/2        2012-10-23 11:01 (:0)
  lars     pts/2        2012-10-23 11:11 (:0)
  lars     pts/2        2012-10-23 11:43 (:0)
  lars     pts/2        2012-10-23 12:41 (:0)
  lars     pts/2        2012-10-23 12:41 (:0)
  ```
- Let's try placing "lars" with "superman":

  ```
  $ sed -i s/lars/superman/ wtmp.work
  ```
- And see what happened:

  ```
  $ who wtmp.work
  superman pts/7        1969-12-31 19:00
  ```

Oops.

Hopefully that answers your question!

Comment: Oddly enough it didn't work for me, perhaps it is my syntax. Thanks